# My JavaScript does not check my form's radio-inputs correctly

Tags: javascript, html, radio-button, alert

So I am trying to write javaScript to check my form. I have six radio-type inputs, of which one **has** to be checked. The radiobuttons are placed in two rows of three radio-inputs. One row has the name 'inschrijving1' and the other three inputs of the other row each has the name 'inschrijving2'. This is the code I used to check the form, but with this code it always returns as false and it always gives an alert.

```
if(!document.getElementsByName("inschrijving1").checked || !document.getElementsByName("inschrijving2").checked)
{
     alert("Selecteer een dagdeel voor de inschrijving");
     return false;
}
```

Can anyone see why this is? I only need it to return false and give an alert if none of the six radio-inputs is checked.

Comment: I suspect, `getElementsByName` returns an array, because it's plural.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because `getElementsByName()` returns a collection/nodeList of elements, which doesn't have a collective `checked` property. To do this, you'd need to explicitly iterate over *each* element returned and check them individually.

Assuming you've only got one element of each `name`:

```
if(!document.getElementsByName("inschrijving1")[0].checked || !document.getElementsByName("inschrijving2")[0].checked)
```

Or, in a compliant browser, with more than one of each:

```
if(!document.querySelector("name=['inschrijving1']:checked") || !document.getElementsByName("name=['inschrijving2']:checked"))
```

`document.querySelector()` returns only the *first* matching (using CSS selector syntax) element that satisfies the supplied selector.

References:

- [`document.getElementsByName()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.getElementsByName).
- [`document.querySelector()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/document.querySelector).

Comment: Thanks! I see what I did wrong here. But now the whole form-checking-script doesnt work anymore (since this was only a bit of all the checks I did).. The whole form is being checked validate even is everything is left unchecked..

Comment: Well, given the lack of any other information whatsoever, I'm not sure how you expect me to help with that?

Comment: I'm sorry it was not nice of me to comment that. I'll just try to figure it out myself for now, thanks for your help so far! :)

Comment: I'm happy to help (and the problem isn't that you weren't 'nice' (you were perfectly polite), it's just that I *can't* help unless I can see more of what's going on) if you provide more code, but I susspect that the problem is probably worthy of a separate question (since this particular aspect of the problem seems to have been adequately addressed). :)